# Can Z3 output "anything" for unconstrained values of UF?

Tags: z3

Some values of uninterpreted functions can be unconstrained during the search. For example, if in smt query only `f(1)` is called, then `f(2)`, `f(3)` can be anything. Is there a way (some option may be) to know which values were not used during the solving and therefore can be anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For quantifier free problems, you can achieve that by using the option `:model-partial` to `true`.
Here is an example (also available [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/7t5)):

```
(set-option :model-partial true)

(declare-fun f (Int) Int)

(assert (> (f 0) 0))
(assert (< (f 1) 0))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

In this example, we get the output:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun f ((x!1 Int)) Int
    (ite (= x!1 0) 1
    (ite (= x!1 1) (- 1)
      #unspecified)))
)
```

BTW, in the next release (Z3 4.3.2), this option is renamed to `:model.partial`. In the next release, the options are grouped in modules.

Comment: Bug or Feature? -- changing `:model-partial` from false to true causes changing the status from `sat` to `unknown` (or it is because of forall quantifiers?). Here is the query: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/444947/posts/from_sat_to_unknown.smt2

Comment: This is not a bug. The query in your link contains quantifiers. The quantifiers will not be satisfied by partial functions. Quantifier free problems can be satisfied by partial functions because we only need to define their values in a finite number of "places".